# Heroku gives wrongly formatted error vs Local is working fine

Tags: heroku

The application works fine locally. However deploying it in heroku gives the following error without any clue

com.github.dandelion.core.DandelionException: The file
'WEB-INF/classes/dandelion/my-bundle.json' is wrongly formatted.

Please help me on how to resolve this.

Below is the JSON file for reference.

Below is the json file used in the deployment for your reference.

```
{
"bundle" : "my-bundle",
"assets": [
    {
        "name": "jquery",
        "version": "2.1.1",
        "type": "js",
        "locations": {
            "webapp": "/webjars/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "datatables",
        "version": "1.10.5",
        "type": "js",
        "locations": {
            "webapp": "/webjars/datatables/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "datatables",
        "version": "1.10.5",
        "type": "css",
        "locations": {
            "webapp": "/webjars/datatables/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the content of that file `WEB-INF/classes/dandelion/my-bundle.json` in Heroku? Maybe it was somehow broken while deployment. How did you deploy it?

Comment: The json seems to be a valid one and it's not broken as per the json spec and verified with the online validator as well. Attached the json file above for your reference.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant if it doesn't contain for example UTF-8 BOM or something like that. Check it with HEX viewer/editor.

Comment: I checked with Notepad++ view all characters and don't find anything related to the same. even after removing the entire content, i am getting the same error message.

Comment: Check it with HEX viewer/editor as I wrote, please. UTF-8 BOM won't be visible in Notepad++ even if you enable displaying of whitespace characters. Also it will be present even in completely empty file. I checked both right now. UTF-8 BOM characters are 3 bytes and look like "ď»ż", hexa EF BB BF (displayed by TotalCommander's Lister).

Comment: I have checked with HEX editor as well as with BOM detector and characters are fine and no illegal characters found

Comment: OK. BTW it seems the exception is thrown in in [this file](https://github.com/dandelion/dandelion/blob/a93e15d63473f70ac8377b9a931deab870a9a78e/dandelion-core/src/main/java/com/github/dandelion/core/bundle/loader/strategy/JsonBundleLoadingStrategy.java) on line 115, but message should be `is wrongly formatted for the following reason: " + e.getMessage()` - are you really missing the part "*for the following reason:*"?